# Would not let me run the application

Tags: java

```
package aaa;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class pear {

    public class aaa extends Application{
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage){
            Button okbt = new Button("ok");
            Scene scene = new Scene(okbt, 200,250);
            primaryStage.setTitle("n");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Application.launch(args);
        }
      }
    }
```

This is the an example of codes that my text book had for me and I try to run it but it wouldn't run. This is the error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class aaa.pear, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args).
```

I don't understand why its wrong because the main class is outside of the start class and inside of the extends Application. This is directly from a book I just need to know why it won't run.

Answer (score 3):

`static` methods can only be declared in a static or top level class rather than in a non-static nested class. In this case its simpler just to use the latter

```
public class MyPearApp extends Application {

   public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `main` method is in an inner class (`aaa`). Try putting it directly in the `pear` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Everything should be Inside main method:

For Example:

```
public class pear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Logic and Everything else goes in here
}
```